# Regex for coordinates [0:0:0] in in square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get this regex pattern to work. I used regex101 to test it and it worked on there. However, is not working in my script. The pattern is as follows:

```
The radar detected one fleet from\[(\d{1,2}:\d{1,3}:\d{1})] is flying toward our Planet \[(\d{1,2}:\d{1,3}:\d{1})], arrival time left (\d{1,2}h\d{1,2}m\d{1,2}s). Enemy consist of: (.*)
```

Sample text is below:

> The radar detected one fleet from[1:124:3] is flying toward our Planet [10:1:6], arrival time left 0h43m1s. Enemy consist of: Small Cargo(1), Large Cargo(1), Light Fighter(1), Heavy Fighter(1), Cruiser(1), Battleship(1), Colony Ship(1), Recycle Ship(1), Spy Probe(1), Bomber(1), Destroyer(1), Dreadnought(1), Death Star(1)

The regex should capture the first set of co-ordinates (the numbers between the `[ ]`) , the second set of co-ordinates, the arrival time, and then everything after `Enemy Consist of:`.

The code I'm using in in the script is

```
preg_match($regex,$text,$matches);
```

with `$regex` being the pattern at the top and `$text` being similar to the sample text, but `$matches` is not being set.

Comment: i think you forget to add the delimiters.

Comment: and escape the closing bracket `\]`

Comment: Can you post the code snippet itself? It would make things a lot easier on this end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression works as expected, the problem is that you are missing [**delimiters**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your pattern. You may also want to escape the dot `.` to match a literal. Otherwise, it means match any single character except newline.

A delimiter can be any *non-alphanumeric*, *non-backslash*, *non-whitespace character*.

```
$text = 'The radar detected one fleet from[1:124:3] is flying toward our Planet [10:1:6], arrival time left 0h43m1s. Enemy consist of: Small Cargo(1), Large Cargo(1), Light Fighter(1), Heavy Fighter(1), Cruiser(1), Battleship(1), Colony Ship(1), Recycle Ship(1), Spy Probe(1), Bomber(1), Destroyer(1), Dreadnought(1), Death Star(1)';
$regex = '/The radar detected one fleet from\[(\d{1,2}:\d{1,3}:\d{1})] is flying toward our Planet \[(\d{1,2}:\d{1,3}:\d{1})], arrival time left (\d{1,2}h\d{1,2}m\d{1,2}s)\. Enemy consist of: (.*)/i';
preg_match($regex, $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(322) "The radar detected one fleet from[1:124:3] is flying toward our Planet [10:1:6], arrival time left 0h43m1s. Enemy consist of: Small Cargo(1), Large Cargo(1), Light Fighter(1), Heavy Fighter(1), Cruiser(1), Battleship(1), Colony Ship(1), Recycle Ship(1), Spy Probe(1), Bomber(1), Destroyer(1), Dreadnought(1), Death Star(1)"
  [1]=> string(7) "1:124:3"
  [2]=> string(6) "10:1:6"
  [3]=> string(7) "0h43m1s"
  [4]=> string(196) "Small Cargo(1), Large Cargo(1), Light Fighter(1), Heavy Fighter(1), Cruiser(1), Battleship(1), Colony Ship(1), Recycle Ship(1), Spy Probe(1), Bomber(1), Destroyer(1), Dreadnought(1), Death Star(1)"
}
```